# Call Button OnClick from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a button as follows,

```
<Button Height="40" Width="40" x:Name="btnup" Command="{Binding UpCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dgEntities,Path=SelectedItem}" Click="Btnup_OnClick">
```

In the ViewModel I have a UpCommand and in the XAML.cs I have Btnup_OnClick event. Is there a possibility to call Btnup_OnClick event in the UpCommand in the viewmodel. Please help. I want the command to be executed after OnClick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't call a codebehind function from the viewmodel (And you probably shouldn't either, it kind of defeats the purpose of having a VM).

If you want to coordinate two separate functions, you can call a view model function from the codebehind by getting the datacontext of the page:

```
private void Btnup_OnClick(){
  //DO YOUR OTHER STUFF HERE
  var viewModel = (MyViewModelClass)DataContext;
  viewModel.UpCommand();
}
```

Comment: Actually for the UpCommand parameter I am passing the selected row of a datagrid. How do I pass it from view.

Comment: You could bind the SelectedItem property of the Grid to a viewModel property. Then it'll be accessible in the viewmodel. 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedThing, Mode=TwoWay}"